# data structure problems

Tags: data-structures

Please help me in finding the optimized solutions to these interesting data structure questions:

1. Given a file containing approx 10 million words, design a data structure for finding the anagrams
2. Write a program to display the ten most frequent words in a file such that your program be efficient in all complexity measures.
3. You have a file with millions of lines of data. Only two lines are identical; the rest are all unique. Each line is so long that it may not even fit in the memory. What is the most efficient solution for finding the identical lines?

Adding some more questions:

4) (asked by MS) You are given an array of Strings of length 3. One of the string in the array is marked as Start string and another one as End string. You have to convert start string to end string, given the condition that the intermediate string which you will make should differ from its previous string by only one character and the string should be present in the input array.
eg. If input is

```
Array: {"fat", "tab", "eat", "see", "tub", "fab", "rat", "sel"}
Start: "fat"
End: "tub"
Then the output should be 
fat -> fab -> tab -> tub
```

I had tried to solve the third one and had come up with two possible appraoches:
1) Read only the first word of all the lines and then eliminate all those lines whose first word does not match the first word of any other line. Keep getting the successive words of the remaining lines in this manner until you are left with just two lines. You got your answer!
2) Convert each line into a smaller representation. This can be achieved by coding each word in short binary form and then XORing the bits representing each line.

Edit: I now have a good collection of data-structure problems with me, if anyone is interested in discussing them here, then I can post some more.

Comment: @S.Lott: If I write 'em Ashish can take the job.  I'll just take the paycheck :)

Comment: @Jason Punyon: Since it was my idea, I want 15%.  You can have the rest.

Comment: they look like fun - post your code so far ashish ;)

Comment: @S.Lott: You should get a patent on this idea.

Comment: @Jason Punyon: Good idea, I'll give you 15% for having the idea.  Perhaps @Ashish can post some questions on how to patent this.

Comment: @S.Lott: Paycheck - 15% + 15% === Paycheck.  WIN!

Comment: These do look like fun, I hope someone posts some answers. :)

Comment: What's so funny? are they too trivial or have they been posted on this forum before. Some gentleman has already rated them down.

Comment: Ashish: try posting your own attempts and asking for critiques, instead of just asking for the answers.

Comment: I didn't know that is what this forum means by "Ask your question". Quite interesting.

Comment: @S.Lott: A number of times such questions have some optimized solutions. I was looking to get those solutions if anyone else know of them. I am sure this will help a number of other people.

Comment: @Ashish.  What this forum means by "Ask your question" is generally a little more narrow than "ask any random question".  Generally, we deeply resent open-ended questions that are (a) homework, (b) easily found with a Google search or (c) ask us to do work for you.  Your question looks like (c).  If it's not, you are free to fix it to clarify what you want.  Specific, detailed questions are preferred here.  If your question was really bad, we'd vote to close it.  It's not closed: usually that means we have some hope that you'll improve it.

Comment: @S. Lott: It is certainly not a (c). This is not a work which I have been asked to do. Getting the optimized solutions to these questions will surely help a lot of people in opening up their minds towards how to attack such problems. And going by the comments, some people are interested in knowing the answers to these questions.

Comment: @Ashish: Since it's not (c) ("do my work for me"), then it's (a) or (b).  I don't think the answers are trivially available, so that leaves homework.  You might want to flag this [homework] so we're clear that you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: you have exactly share your knowledge .... but buddy there are many other far more intelligent than you and me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I proposed for the 4th question was to make a graph of all the words in the array. 
First create an adjacency matrix which will have a value 1 if a word can be directly converted to another word.

Now use depth first search to find a path from Start string to End string and return the path if found.

Note that you will have to modify the depth first search here to store the path which you have traversed till now. For this, instead of pushing the node which is being visited to Stack, I pushed the complete path till now to the stack, so that when the element is found, I have the complete path from the Start string to the End string.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve the 4th question using hypercubes(in graph theory), so strings of length 3 can be represented in Q3 with the start string as '000' and the strings which differ from the start string can be represented as '001', '100', and '010' respectively, the end string as '111'.

Since hypercubes are connected graphs, we can find at least one path from start string to end string.
If we manage to find the shortest path(which implies that no vertex i.e.,no string is repeated), the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to Q2 can be to use a Hashmap or a TRIE to store the word and its frequency. Both of these structures provide good lookup order. For each word in file, check if the word already exists. If yes, increase its count else add the word and initialize the count to 1.

This question was recently asked to one of my friends in Microsoft interview. The solution he proposed was similar. Maintain a HashMap and a doubly linked list. DLL will be sorted based on the word frequencies. Any time a new word is added to the document, the DLL will be modified accordingly to reflect the current sorted list.

I think the most efficient solution is by using TRIE with a doubly linked list.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the 4th ques can be solved using backtracking, but not sure if that would be the optimal, tried working on it yesterday the solution seems to be working for me.